# How insert ImageStream in VS Resources Manager?

Tags: imagestream

I'm working on 4.5 .Net application and need insert `ImageStream` from old application to new one, `ImageStream` was saved from ilSpy.

I found way to insert existing `ImageStream`, you must open `.resx` file in your new app and add these code.

This works only if res file was created by ResourcesManager ver 4.0.0.0 and above.

```
<data name="imageList_1.ImageStream" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64">
    <value>..here is resource's body in base64 format..</value>
</data>
```

`Imagestream` from subj was created by ResourcesManager 2.0.0.0 (.NET 2.0), when I open it in WordPad, text looks like abracadabra. As I know, it must be in base64 format. I found an online converter, which let me insert text directly from old `.resx` file, I got output base64 text and insert it between tags in code above.

Now I see `ImageStream` in new ResourcesManager in other, however its type is `none/null`, but it should be `System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer`

How to convert `ImageStream` ver 2.0.0.0 to 4.0.0.0?